# Save image from camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is how I show and save from my camera:

```
-(IBAction)Camera:(id)sender{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

        newMedia = YES;
    }
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [self scaleThenRotateImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

        imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }

    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I'm using a picker that uses `ALAsset`,that can multiselect then displays a checkmark on images selected.

So for example I take a picture from my camera(with the code above) then go to my camera roll to select images(multiple/single) with the `imageTaken`, it doesnt display any checkmark when I show the picker, so I'm assuming the solution is I need to save it by/with `ALAsset`.

Should I just change this:

`UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

to

`UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata`

or what should I do/change? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You mean you want to write to the photo albums managed by the photo app? I guess you can't do that, but you can save your image to camera roll if that helps you

Comment: im saving it to camera roll, but when I get the image with imagepicker that uses ALAsset it doesn't recognize it,

Comment: I didn't know Apple let's you use image pickers other than what apple provides, make sure it does not use private api and basically in my mind the problem is with your image picker side, you need to set it to read from camera roll, not the way you save your images, sorry if I am missing something here.

Comment: it can read from camera roll perfectly, though when I use my code for camera as `imageTaken` then pick it in my imagePicker, it doesnt recognize.

Comment: OK, so can you read these photos that you save when you open the photos app (the one from apple), I want to know if the images are not being saved properly or it is a format or metadata issue

Comment: what i want is, when I take a picture from camera, i want to get its `ALAsset` object then pass it in an array,
like this: "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=119A0D2D-C267-4B69-A200-59890B2B0FE5&ex‌​t=JPG"